# Pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics with custom parameter

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

I got uncaught errors form the framework to Crashlytics. But it is difficult to fix the issue because I don't know which screen or record caused the error.

For example below error, I only know that it is invalid image from CacheNetworkImage package. But It is very difficult to find out which screen or which record.

Is there any way to pass screen name or custom parameter. I can't find the way to record.

> Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError:
> Exception: Invalid image data. Error thrown Instance of
> 'ErrorDescription'.
> at .instantiateImageCodec(dart:ui)
> at ImageLoader.loadAsync(_image_loader.dart:59)
> at new MultiImageStreamCompleter.(multi_image_stream_completer.dart:25)

Below code pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics.

```
FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setCustomKey` to add values to reports.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCustomKey('str_key', 'hello');
```

See [Customize your Firebase Crashlytics crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter) for details.